# Is my repentance accepted if the sin is done again (cheating)

Tags: quran, cheating, reciting

assalamualaikum

My mom and dad got me into this Quran reciting school that we have to memorize the verses. I sometimes not ready to recite them to the sheikh so i cheat and read from the Quran i always repent and the next day i do it again. I’m just scared that my repentance isn’t going to be accepted. I just don’t know how to stop it. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

Refer to following Quranic ayah,

> But repentance is not [accepted] of those who [continue to] do evil
> deeds up until, when death comes to one of them, he says, "Indeed, I
> have repented now," or of those who die while they are disbelievers.
> For them We have prepared a painful punishment.
>
> <sup>[Quran 4:18](https://legacy.quran.com/4/18)</sup>

Meaning that for a repentance to be accepted one should stop doing the evil deed and ask for forgiveness and mercy of Allah.

Answer (score 0):

A condition for acceptance of repentance is that one should have the firm intention to not repeat it. However repeating it nonetheless does not effect the validity and hence acceptance of the previous repentance. But if you are repeating a sin everyday then it is doubtful that you have truly repented.